# Prevent onClick of base element if onClick of overlay button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a `<button>` component overlayed on a `<div>` component that is shows an image.

The button component is a red [X] as shown in the picture below. I have a seperate onClick Listener for the  `<button>` and the `<div>`. I want to make sure when the onClick of the button is fired, i.e. the [X] is clicked the onClick of the `<div>` should not run.

How to do this?

I have tried this, but it does not work
First the onClick of the `<button>` runs and then the onCLick of `<div>` runs

```
  const onClickButtonHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("BTN HANDLER")
  };

  const onClickDivHandler = (event) => {
    console.log("DIV HANDLER")
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding code in the onClickButtonHandler that simply removes the onClick handler for the div

Comment: @kspc1000 They are two different events and in two different components, cant be clubbed together in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('mydiv')
        .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log("div clicked")
        });
        
document.getElementById('xAndDiv')
        .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log("x clicked, div click also executes")
        });

document.getElementById('x')
        .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation()
            console.log("only x click executes")
        });
```

```css
.div {
    background-image: url( https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/back_our/20190628/ourmid/pngtree-clear-sample-newspaper-spring-forest-playground-background-design-image_276784.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 250px;
 }
 
 .x {
  color:red;
 }
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="div">
  <button class="x" id="xAndDiv" >X & Div </button>
  <button class="x" id="x" >Only X</button>
</div>
```

You need to stop the propagation of event in the onclick of button

```
const onClickButtonHandler = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("BTN HANDLER")
  };
```

It prevents the event to bubble up to the parent level

codesandbox for react reference https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-thunder-1x0coz?file=/src/App.js

Read more about `stopPropagation` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)